# UITextField blocks scrolling within UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uitextfield

I've got UITextFields within UITableViewCells. The text views seems to be blocking the scrolling. When I put my finger-tip within the text view's bound and try to scroll the whole table, the it won't scroll. Scrolling is fine outside the text views.

How can I stop this behavior?

Answer (score 1):

It seems that the only way to avoid this is subclassing the UIScrollView and implement

```
(BOOL)touchesShouldCancelInContentView:(UIView *)view
```

Then, detect that the view is a UITextField and return YES, else return NO.

Comment: Hey @AntonioMG, I think this is normally the right way to go however when dealing with a table view the UIView object passed to touchesShouldCancelInContentView: always appear to be an instance of UITableViewCellContentView, not the subviews, so don't think you'd be able to test which view was tapped

Comment: i solved it by selecting 'delays content touches' of the table view in the nib

Comment: Cool, i'm gonna try that, would be way easier than the way I did it

Answer (score 1):

This code below is a little hacky but it works for me, basically just set userInteractionEnabled on the UITextView to NO then set to YES when you detect the user has tapped it.  Below is code for my custom cell with the textview, it scrolls fine for me when user initiates scroll from within UITextView.  This works cause the scroll is a pan gesture not a tap.

```
#import "MyCell.h"

@interface MyCell () <UITextFieldDelegate>

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *textField;

@end

@implementation MyCell

- (void)awakeFromNib
{
    self.textField.userInteractionEnabled = NO;
    self.textField.delegate = self;

    UITapGestureRecognizer *tapRecognizer = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(didTap:)];
    [self addGestureRecognizer:tapRecognizer];
}

#pragma mark - Private methods

- (void)didTap:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)tapRecognizer
{
    CGPoint location = [tapRecognizer locationInView:self];

    CGRect pointRect = CGRectMake(location.x, location.y, 1.0f, 1.0f);
    if (!CGRectIsNull(CGRectIntersection(pointRect, self.textField.frame))) {
        self.textField.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
        [self.textField becomeFirstResponder];
    } 
}

#pragma mark - UITextFieldDelegate methods

- (void)textFieldDidEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField
{
    self.textField.userInteractionEnabled = NO;
}

@end
```